# Key Code to Characters?

Tags: javascript

So, I found this macros for my game, online (I had to use pastebin).  It works really well, I have no issue, but I am trying to let my users choose their own key for the event key code, and that requires a knowledge of keycodes which my vistors do not have ( most of them ). So how can I change for ex.

[Full Code Here (PasteBin)](https://pastebin.com/raw/TJTcSHc9)

```
if (event.keyCode == 70) {
        // Solo-tricksplit (f)
```

this to letter "f" insted of Keycode 70?

Comment: create a UI that lets them choose then store that in localStorage and assign it into a variable on page load. If none selected the variable would be assigned default value

Comment: Ascii conversion `String.fromCharCode(70)`

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapping of letters to key-codes:

```
mapper = {'f': 70, 'w': 87, 'c': 67, ...}
```

and then, when the user types 'f' or 'F' you'll do:

```
keycode = mapper[userChoice.lower()];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily bind a listener while you ask the user for their choice of input. Note that `keyCode` is deprecated, but [is likely to still work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown).

```js
var key = 70
var chooser = document.getElementById('keycode-chooser')

document.getElementById('choose-event-key')
  .addEventListener('click', function () { 
    chooser.innerHTML = "Tap the key you'd like to use as the event key:"
    document.addEventListener('keydown', keyCodeChooser)
  })

function keyCodeChooser (evt) {
  chooser.innerHTML = "Setting '" + evt.key + "' as the event key."
  key = evt.keyCode
  chooser.removeEventListener('keydown', keyCodeChooser)
  console.log(key)
}
```

```html
<div id="keycode-chooser"></div>
<button id="choose-event-key">Choose event key</button>
```